# What does Narr or Affe have to do with fressen?

Tags: idiom

Could someone please explain to me the rationale behind this idiom:

> einen Narren or Affen an jdm/etw gefressen haben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple theories about the origin of the phrase. One of them refers to old conceptions of evil possession. If a person was believed to be possessed by for example a demon, it was often thought that the demon was actually *inside* the person's body, influencing their behaviour. From there, it's no big leap to think that the person swallowed the demon, or the demon forced entry through the person's mouth.

In the phrase

> Herr Müller hat einen Narren an seinem Enkel gefressen.

the mental image is that Mister Müller has a fool or a jester inside him, making him behave unusual.

See also related expressions like

> Was ist denn in sie gefahren?
> Der hat wohl einen Clown gefrühstückt!

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a common idiom, is it perhaps regional? I got more hits on *In der Not frisst der Teufel Fliegen.* My literal translation is "When in need, the devil will eat flies." But a better translation is "Beggars can't be choosers."

Comment: @RDBury It's not an expression you would use every day, but I'm not aware of any regional limits. Regarding "In der Not frisst der Teufel fliegen", I wouldn't group that saying together with "einen Narren an jmdn. / etw. gefressen haben". There are a lot of idioms and sayings involving the mouth that aren't necessarily related.

Comment: It's „umgangssprachlich“ (colloquial), sure, but I don't think it's regional. DWDS has it: https://www.dwds.de/wb/an%20jmdm.%2C%20etw.%20einen%20Narren%20gefressen%20haben